# NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/vote/

Tags: django

There are three question on Stack overflow with slightly different error.In mine argument is also being passed but I just don't seem to figure out what the error is?

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/vote/
    Reverse for 'result' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
    Request Method: POST
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/polls/1/vote/
    Django Version: 1.8.2
    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
    Exception Value:    
    Reverse for 'result' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
    Exception Location: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 496
    Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Here is my polls/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import Movie, Rating
# Create your views here.

def detail(request, movie_id):
    try:
        movie = get_object_or_404(Movie,pk = movie_id)
    except Movie.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Movie not found")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'movie': movie})

def result(request, movie_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk = movie_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/result.html', {'movie': movie})

def vote(request, movie_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Movie, pk = movie_id)
    try:
        selected_rating = p.rating_set.get(pk=request.POST['rating'])
    except(KeyError, Rating.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'movie':p, 'error_message':"you didn't select a rating",})
    else:
        selected_rating.votes += 1
        selected_rating.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:result', args=(p.id,)))
```

Please ask me if you need any additional file I will put them here.

Here is detail.html

```
<h1> {{movie.movie_text}}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' movie.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for rating in movie.rating_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ rating.id }}" />
    <label for="rating{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ rating.rating_number }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

and here is result.html

```
<h1>{{movie.movie_text}}</h1>

<ul>
    {% for rating in movie.rating_set.all%}
    <li>{{rating.rating_text}} -- {{rating.votes }} vote{{rating.votes|pluralize}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' movie.id %}">Vote Again? </a>
```

Here is polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #ex: /polls/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    #ex /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<movie_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    url(r'^(?P<movie_id>[0-9]+)/result/$', views.result, name='results'),

    url(r'^(?P<movie_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

Here is mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
]
```

Comment: You've showed a lot of code, but not the relevant bits which are the urls.py files.

Comment: newbie here, I have put the urls.py file

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a view named "polls:result", you have one named "polls:results". Either change the name in polls/urls.py, or the value you use in the call to `reverse` in the `vote` view.

Comment: Is there any way to find these syntax mistakes other than looking at it ?

Comment: You could try yelling at it. Other than that: PyCharm doesn't even pick it up, and I believe that's the only real Django-specific IDE. The error message tells you something, though: if it shows `0 pattern(s) tried`, you are generally using the wrong url name (or your patterns are broken), but if it tried some patterns, you generally have the right name but the wrong arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error cause I was not returning redirect instead I was trying to render the 'detail.html' template when the post was successful

Comment: Please add some information to your answer to further help address this question.